# Execute a method only once at start of an Apache Storm topology

Tags: apache-storm

If I have a simple Apache Storm topology with a spout (set to a parallelism of 2) running on two separate nodes. How can I write a method that will be run once, and only once, at the start of the topology before any processing of tuples has begun?

Any implementation of a singleton/static class, or synchronized method alone will not work, as the two instances are running on separate nodes.

Perhaps there are some Storm methods that I can use to decide if I'm the first Spout to be instantiated, and run only then? I tried playing around with the getThisTaskId() & getThisWorkerTasks() methods, but was unsuccessful.

NOTE: The parallelism of 2 is to keep things simple. A solution should work for any number of nodes/workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Thought of an easier solution. I'll leave the original answer below in case it is helpful.

You can use `TopologyContext.getThisTaskIndex` to do this. If you make your spout `open` method run the code only if `TopologyContext.getThisTaskIndex == 0`, then your code will run only once, before any tuples are emitted.

If the worker that ran this code crashes, the code will be run again when the spout instance with task index 0 is restarted. In order to fix this, you can use Zookeeper to store state that should carry over across restarts, e.g. put a flag in Zookeeper once the only-once code has run, and have the spout `open` check that the flag is not set before running the code.

You can use `TopologyContext.getStormId` to get a constant unique string to identify the topology, so you can tell whether the flag was set by this topology or a previous deployment.

Original answer:

The easiest way to run some code only once on deployment of a topology, is to call the code when you submit the topology. You can call the only-once code at the same time as you wire your topology with `TopologyBuilder`. This will only get run once. The downside is it will run on the machine you're calling `storm jar` from.

If you for some reason can't do it this way or need to run the code from one of the worker nodes, there isn't anything built in to Storm to allow you to do this. The reason there isn't such a mechanism is that it requires extra coordination between the worker JVMs, and I don't think anyone has needed something like this.

The best option for you would probably be to look at Zookeeper/Curator to do this coordination (see https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/index.html). This should allow you to make only one worker in the cluster run your code. You'll have to consider what should happen if the worker chosen to run your code crashes/stalls.

Storm already uses Zookeeper for coordination, so you can just connect to that cluster.

Comment: This worked for me! Your edited method was the one I went with.